# Google Spreadsheets - COUNTIFS formula for the last 20 cells of an expanding column

Tags: google-sheets

I have a column of data which keeps expanding over time, I want a formule that states how many times a certain word appears within the last 20 cells of that column. Is that possible?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Please [edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/171507/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with another table that shows your _manually entered_ desired results. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sortn()` and `countif()`, like this:

```
=countif( 
  sortn(A1:A, 20, 0, row(A1:A) * not(isblank(A1:A)), false), 
  "certain" 
)
```

See [sortn()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7354624) and [countif()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093480).

Comment: Thank you! I get the gist of it but it's not quite working yet and I think its because the cells that are "blank" are not actually blank but have formulas in them which I have said IF(cell=0,""). Is there a way I can change the 'isblank' for something that will work?

Comment: It makes little sense to fill a spreadsheet with zero-length text strings. Replace `if(cell = 0, "", 42)` with `if(cell, 42, iferror(ø))`.